# What does そうでも思わないと…… mean?

Tags: translation

```
沈んだユグドラシルのエンジン、今頃深い沙の下で泣いてるのかなぁ……。                    
いや、あいつはあそこで眠ってるんだ。 あそこが一番安らかに眠れる場所にちがいない。   
そうでも思わないと……。
```

I'm not really understand this sentence - そうでも思わないと……

I think it's - **I guess you don't think so......** or - **If we don't believe so......**

Is there some part omited here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this sentence by itself literally means "if I don't believe so", and the remaining part is left unsaid. The "full" version would be something along the lines of そうでも思わないと[やりきれない](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) or そうでも思わないとあまりに悲しい.